# How can I generate HTML reports from python?

Tags: python, html, report

I am trying to generate reports. I'd first need to manipulate the data from python and I'd like to present the data in a nice report thereafter. After googling it seems like this method (https://plot.ly/python/html-reports/) would be ideal for me.

I have 2 questions.

1) Based on (https://plot.ly/python/html-reports/), should I be creating the python script all in 1 file? Or should I separate them.

2) Are there other ways I can use to generate such reports?